# Directing Xcode Image into image view

Tags: xcode, image, uiimageview

Hi Quick question really currently I'm trying to connect my image to my image view within Xcode and currently when I run the program y image appears but it does so in the top left hand corner, I just wanted to know what line of code I was missing in order to navigate my image directly into one of my images views.

Thanks

```
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
    //Allocating space for the image

                            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TESTPIC.jpg"]];

    //Selecting the image

                                           [self.view addSubview:myImage];

    //Displaying the Image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the frame property of UIImageView. Please find the below code for more information.

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                        //Allocating space for the image

                        initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];


myImage.frame = CGRectMake(your x position, your y position, myImage.frame.size.width, myImage.frame.size.height);

//Selecting the image

[self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

Hope it works.